# How can I prevent my HighChart bar chart from being inverted?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

For some odd reason the [documentation for HighChart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.inverted) says that the bar chart is automatically inverted. I don't want this, does anybody have a work around?

Comment: Default means you can set it's value, if you don't the default will be used. So set it to `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was a question of terminology.

What I call a Gantt chart, is called a bar chart and what I call a bar chart they call a column chart.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the options so that Highcharts does not reverse the order of the series of the x-axis, therefore the axis are inverted but the bar series themselves are not inverted:

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...
    xAxis: {
        reversed: false
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K5tpe/

Highcharts Documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.reversed

Answer (score 1):

i met the same problem with this , none of the answers helps , but i changed the source code of highcharts.js, 
    pa = ka(wa, {
        type: "bar",
        inverted: !0
    });
this place forced the charts for bar to be inverted , so i can only change the source code to remove the default behavior, like this
    pa = ka(wa, {
        type: "bar",
        inverted: 0
    });

today i found i am so silly , just use "column" type ,"column" and "bar" are inverted

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just poorly phrased documentation - "**When true**, the x axis is reversed by default" (my emph) It actually does what you'd expect by default! (i.e. the "by default" part of the sentence is very misleading!)

If you look at the sample code in jsFiddle via the "Try It" link in the documentation you'll see the line:

> inverted: true

This setting is overriding the default behaviour, if you remove it and click run you'll see normal service resume!

Answer (score 0):

By default highchart set:

```
inverted: false
```

so you not need to worry, I you set it `true` then it will be inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems in the most recent version v4.2.3 it is `false` by default.